# Android/JSON: Json Response is false?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am currently creating an `Android Application` that is linked to a `PHPMyAdmin` `MYSQL` database on 
Hosting24.com, this activity is intended to allow the user to sign up to enter details in an EditText box in the application that will be entered into the MYSQL database.

The code that I am attempting to run is giving a `Toast` output of:

`"Sorry, Username already chosen. Please choose another. "` eventhough the datbase is completely empty.

This seems to be because the `JSON response` is false, my query is **why** would this be false?

Would it mean that the `Access details` in the PHP script are incorrect?

**Android Code:**

```
public class SignUp extends Activity {

    EditText UserName, Password;
    Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_screen);

        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.euUserName);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.euPass);
        Password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSingUp);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // get The User name and Password to sign up with
                String userName = UserName.getText().toString();
                String password = Password.getText().toString();

                // Url to login PHP script on server  
                String serverURL = "http://r999hosting.com/UserRegistrationService.php?username="
                        + userName + "&password=" + password;

                new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Contains logic related to communication with PHP script over server
     * 
     * @author
     * 
     */
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        String data = "";
        int sizeData = 0;

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait.. ");
            Dialog.show();

        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // make POST call to web server
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                // Define URL where to send data
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                // Send POST data request
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();

                // Get the server response
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "");
                }

                // Append Server Response To Content String
                Content = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {

                    reader.close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {

            } else {

                // Start Parse Response JSON Data
                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {

                    // Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from
                    // the JSON string
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                    String result = jsonResponse.get("result").toString();

                    if (result.equals("true")) {
                        // inform user they have signed up successfully
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,
                                "Congrats: Sign Up Successfull",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent i = new Intent(SignUp.this,
                                LoginHome.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        // inform user of error signing up
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Congrats: Sign Up Successfull",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                SignUp.this,
                                "Sorry, Username already chosen. Please choose another. ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }


}
```

**PHP Script: (Note: real details not shown for security reasons)**

```
<?php



if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{

$mysql_host = " ";
$mysql_database = " ";
$mysql_user = " ";
$mysql_password = " ";


// Provide host ip, mysql user name, password
 $con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

// Provide database name.
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);



    $username=$_GET['username'];

    $password=$_GET['password'];

    $flag="false";


    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {

        $sql="Insert into `Login` (`UserName`,`Password`)  values ('$username','$password') ";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if($result)
        {
            $count= mysql_affected_rows();
            if($count > 0)
            {
                $flag="true"; //result true 

            }               

        }

                   mysql_close($con);
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$flag));
    }



}

?>
```

Comment: Does the database exist? Does it have the correct schema? So many things could go wrong. Why don't you check the mysql error and return it in the result as well?

Answer (score 0):

you have the `userName` and `password` hard coded into URL, which will be OK for `GET` but not for `POST`; For `POST` request you need to send the query parameters in request body.

Pass the query string separately to your background task, so you can set the `data` field with it.

```
    // Url to login PHP script on server  
        String serverURL = "http://r999hosting.com/UserRegistrationService.php"

        String query = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
        new LongOperation().execute(serverURL, query);
```

you may want to [properly encode the query see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

change your `doInBackground` to set local `data` variable.

```
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            data = urls[1]
            ...
```